# Inequality of multiple integral

Tags: multiple-integral

How to prove following inequality :
$$ \iint_V \frac{dxdy}{x^{-1} + \mid \ln y \mid -1} \le 1, V = [0, 1]×[0, 1]$$
Could you say me how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This answer wasn't correct, unfortunately...

Comment: By the way, you should take $V=(0,1]\times (0,1]$ instead, to avoid the undefined expressions $0^{-1}$ and $\ln 0$.

Comment: Oops, sorry, $|\ln y| \ge 1$ wasn't right! Don't know what I was thinking there... Please unaccept so that I can delete this answer.